# Why defining a macro of parenthesis-enclosing pointer type not allowed in C?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Why is the following code resulting in compilation error:

```
#define PASS_TYPE(x) (x*)

void foo(PASS_TYPE(int) a) {
    // ...
}
```

The error says:

```
main.cc:3:6: error: variable or field 'foo' declared void
    3 | void foo(PASS_TYPE(int) a) {
      |      ^~~
main.cc:3:25: error: 'a' was not declared in this scope
    3 | void foo(PASS_TYPE(int) a) {
      |                         ^
```

Comment: you want to create a pointer to that type by macro? Why? And choose either C or C++, not both. Anyway it should be `#define TYPE_PTR(x) (x)*`

Comment: The notation `(type *)` is a cast operator (C-style cast operator in C++ — the only type of cast in C).  If you're trying to cast a value, the parenthesized form works and the unparenthesized form does not. If you're trying to declare a variable, the unparenthesized form works and the parenthesized form does not.  But why would you want to make your users (maybe that's just you) type 9 extra characters to confuse the reader — especially when the notation doesn't work reliably.

Comment: Note, too, that you can only declare a single variable at a time with the unparenthesized notation: `TYPE_PTR(int) x, y;` defines one pointer, `x`, and one plain `int`, `y`.

Comment: This is really a C syntax question.  For example, `int *x;` is a valid declaration, but `(int *)x;` is not.  C doesn't allow parentheses around type specifiers in a declaration.  They may only be used with declarators.

Comment: To answer the question in your title: yes, you can define a macro that is enclosed in parentheses - and people do it often - but you can of course only use it where its expansion is correct.

Comment: @phuclv, to answer why using a macro for a pointer type, the context of the macro is actually in C++ where I am using it as a dispatcher. Pointer-of is just the current definition and is subject to change. To answer why both C and C++, it applies to both.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, thanks for your digest and I think that is the best answer (if this question gets reopened so I can mark it).

Comment: My comments are just comments, not an answer.  I'm glad they were useful.  I'm not convinced the question warrants being reopened.  If it is reopened, I'll happily convert my comments into an answer.